# Grokking Java culture - why are things so heavy? What does it optimize for?

Tags: java, programming-languages, programming-practices

I used to code in Python a lot. Now, for work reasons, I code in Java. The projects I do are rather small, and possibly Python would work better, but there are valid non-engineering reasons to use Java (I can't go into details).

Java syntax is no issue; it is just another language. But apart from the syntax, Java has a culture, a set of development methods, and practices that is considered "correct". And for now I am completely failing to "grok" that culture. So I would really appreciate explanations or pointers in the right direction.

A minimal complete example is available in a Stack Overflow question that I started: *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43619566/returning-a-result-with-several-values-the-java-way/43620339*

I have a task - parse (from a single string) and handle a set of three values. In Python it is a one-liner (tuple), in Pascal or C a 5-liner record/struct.

According to the answers, the equivalent of a struct is available in Java syntax and a triple is available in a widely-used Apache library - yet the "correct" way of doing it is actually by creating a separate class for the value, complete with getters and setters. Someone was very kind to provide a complete example. It was 47 lines of code (well, some of these lines were blanks).

I understand that a huge development community is likely not "wrong". So this is a problem with my understanding.

Python practices optimize for readability (which, in that philosophy, leads to maintainability) and after that, development speed. C practices optimize for resource usage. What do Java practices optimize for? My best guess is scalability (everything should be in a state ready for a millions-LOC project), but it is a very weak guess.

Comment: wont answer the technical aspects of the question but still in context : https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/63145/13899

Comment: You may enjoy Steve Yegge's essay [Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns](https://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)

Comment: Please remember that **[comments are for requesting clarification from the author, leaving constructive criticism that guides in improving the post, or adding relevant but minor or transient information](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)**. Please use [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) for any extended discussions.

Comment: Relevant is the essay "Object Oriented Programming is an expensive disaster which must end" --  http://www.smashcompany.com/technology/object-oriented-programming-is-an-expensive-disaster-which-must-end

Comment: Here is what I think is the right answer. You aren't groking Java because you think about programming like a sysadmin, not a programmer.
To you, software is something that you use to achieve a particular task in the most expedient manner. I've been writing Java code for 20 years, and some of the projects I've worked on have take a team of 20, 2 years to achieve. Java is not a replacement for Python nor vice versa. They both do their jobs, but their jobs are entirely different.

Comment: IMO the point of all those formalisms of Java is mainly to ensure the correctness and robustness of code, as well as a rigid, unified standard for the whole team to adhere to. That's what happens in huge enterprises. The development process is extremely detailed and takes a lot of time, but they can afford it. Now whether you and I as developers would like such practices/think of it as worth the effort is another matter.

Comment: The reason that Java is the de-facto standard is because it is simply right.
It was created right, first time, by serious people who had beards before beards were fashionable. If you're used to knocking up shell scripts to manipulate files, Java seems intolerably bloated.
But if you want to create a dual redundant server cluster capable of serving 50M people a day, backed by clustered redis caching, 3 billing systems and a 20M pound oracle database cluster.. You're not going to be using python, even if accessing the database in Python is 25 lines less code.

Comment: I'm going to say the simple answer is because of Eclipse. The two routes the language could have taken were to move towards more concision, or build tools to manage the verbosity. Java went with managing the verbosity. None of it is necessary, and in fact there are safer, stronger, far more terse systems.

It's not marketed to developers either. It's marketed to enterprises. As such it does not have to be appealing to developers. If you do think Java is appealing as a developer, then I'm sorry, but you're either suffering from Stockholm Syndrome, or you've somehow never used anything better.

Comment: 1) Splitting a string is not parsing, it is tokenising.  2) Java could split the string in one line as well with str.split(..) 3) Parsing is about information not data, it includes an element of context and meaning.  4) Tuples come in many sizes (N-Tuples) creating a specific class for the context promotes type safety. 4) Python is optimised for brevity not meaning; in the small those are the same; in the large not so much.

Answer (score 240):

## The Java Language

I believe all these answers are missing the point by trying to ascribe intent to the way Java works. Java's verbosity does not stem from it being object oriented, as Python and many other languages are too yet have terser syntax. Java's verbosity doesn't come from its support of access modifiers either. Instead, it's simply how Java was designed and has evolved.

Java was originally created as a slightly improved C with OO. As such Java has 70s-era syntax. Furthermore, Java is very conservative about adding features in order to retain backward compatibility and to allow it to stand the test of time. Had Java added trendy features like XML literals in 2005 when XML was all the rage the language would have been bloated with ghost features that nobody cares about and that limit its evolution 10 years later. Therefore Java simply lacks a lot of modern syntax to express concepts tersely.

However, there's nothing fundamental preventing Java from adopting that syntax. For example, Java 8 added lambdas and method references, greatly reducing verbosity in many situations. Java could similarly add support for compact data type declarations such as Scala's case classes. But Java simply hasn't done so. Do note that custom value types are on the horizon and this feature may introduce a new syntax for declaring them. I suppose we will see.

---

## The Java Culture

The history of enterprise Java development has largely led us to the culture we see today. In the late 90s/early 00s, Java became an extremely popular language for server-side business applications. Back then those applications were largely written ad-hoc and incorporated many complex concerns, such as HTTP APIs, databases, and processing XML feeds.

In the 00s it became clear that many of these applications had a lot in common and frameworks to manage these concerns, like the Hibernate ORM, the Xerces XML parser, JSPs and the servlet API, and EJB, became popular. However, while these frameworks reduced the effort to work in the particular domain that they set to automate, they required configuration and coordination. At the time, for whatever reason, it was popular to write frameworks to cater to the most complex use case and therefore these libraries were complicated to set up and integrate. And over time they grew increasingly complex as they accumulated features. Java enterprise development gradually became more and more about plugging together third party libraries and less about writing algorithms.

Eventually the tedious configuration and management of enterprise tools became painful enough that frameworks, most notably the Spring framework, came along to manage the management. You could put all your configuration in one place, the theory went, and the configuration tool would then configure the pieces and wire them together. Unfortunately these "framework frameworks" [added more abstraction and complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14636178/unsure-if-i-understand-transactionawarepersistencemanagerfactoryproxy) on top of the whole ball of wax.

Over the past few years more lightweight libraries have grown in popularity. Nonetheless an entire generation of Java programmers came of age during the growth of heavy enterprise frameworks. Their role models, those developing the frameworks, wrote factory factories and proxy configuration bean loaders. They had to configure and integrate these monstrosities day-to-day. And as a result the culture of the community as a whole followed the example of these frameworks and tended to badly over-engineer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57858/discussion-on-answer-by-solomonoffs-secret-grokking-java-culture-why-are-thin).

Comment: What's funny is that other languages seem to be picking up some "java-isms". PHP OO features are heavily inspired by Java, and nowadays JavaScript is often criticized for its huge amount of frameworks and how hard it is to gather all the dependencies and start a new application.

Comment: @marcus maybe because some people finally learned the "do not reinvent the wheel" thing ? Dependencies are the cost of not reinventing the wheel after all

Comment: @Walfrat And [here's](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/03/rage-quit-coder-unpublished-17-lines-of-javascript-and-broke-the-internet/) a lovely example of why going overboard with that can be just as problematic (well the better example is trying to update the dependencies in a modern JS application - the complexities of that are still not completely understood). Having a million 10 line dependencies is just as bad as implementing everything yourself.

Comment: _"Terse"_ often translates into arcane, _"clever"_, code-golf-ish one-liners.

Comment: Thoughtful, well-written answer. Historical context. Relatively unopinionated. Nicely done.

Comment: @TulainsCórdova I agree that we should "avoid...clever tricks like the plague" (Donald Knuth), but that doesn't mean writing a `for` loop when a `map` would be more appropriate (and readable). There's a happy medium.

Comment: May I say that the bean pattern predate by a lot "Hibernate ORM, the Xerces XML parser, JSPs and the servlet API, and EJB"

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I'm pretty sure it was Dijkstra who said that, not Knuth.

Comment: @Ray You're right, my bad. Can't edit it, though.

Answer (score 74):

I believe I have an answer for one of the points you raise that haven't been raised by others.

**Java optimizes for compile-time programmer errors detection by never making any assumptions**

In general, Java tends to only infer facts about the source code after the programmer has already explicitly expressed his intent. The Java compiler never makes any assumptions about the code and will only use inference to reduce redundant code.

The reason behind this philosophy is that the programmer is only human. What we write is not always what we actually intend the program to do. The Java language tries to mitigate some of those issues by forcing developer to always explicitly declare their types. That's just a way of double checking that the code that was written actually does what was intended.

Some other languages push that logic even further by checking pre-conditions, post-conditions and invariants (though I'm not sure they do it at compile time). These are even more extreme ways for the programmer to have the compiler double check his own work.

In your case, this means that in order for the compiler to guarantee that you are actually returning the types that you think you are returning, you need to provide that information to the compiler.

In Java there are two ways to do that:

1. Use `Triplet<A, B, C>` as return type (which really should be in `java.util`, and I can't really explain why it isn't. Especially since JDK8 introduce `Function`, `BiFunction`, `Consumer`, `BiConsumer`, etc... It just seems that `Pair` and `Triplet` at least would make sense. But I digress)
2. Create your own value type for that purpose, where each field is named and typed properly.

In both of those cases, the compiler can guarantee that your function returns the types it declared, and that the caller realizes what is the type of each returned field and uses them accordingly.

Some languages do provide static type checking AND type inference at the same time, but that leaves the door open for a subtle class of type mismatch issues. Where the developer intended to return a value of a certain type, but actually returns another and the compiler STILL accepts the code because it happens that, by co-incidence both the function and the caller only use methods that can be applied to both the intended and the actual types.

Consider something like this in Typescript (or flow type) where type inference is used instead of explicit typing.

```
function parseDurationInMillis(csvLine){
    // here the developer intends to return a Number, 
    // but actually it's a String
    return csv.firstField();
}

// Compiler infers that parseDurationInMillis is String, so it does
// string concatenation and infers that plusTwoSeconds is String
// Developer actually intended Number
var plusTwoSeconds = 2000 + parseDurationInMillis(csvLine);
```

This is a silly trivial case, of course, but it can be a lot more subtle and lead to difficult to debug issues, because the code *looks* right. This kind of issues is entirely avoided in Java, and that is what the whole language is designed around.

---

Note that following the proper Object Oriented principles and domain-driven modeling, the duration parsing case in the linked question could also be returned as a `java.time.Duration` object, which would be a lot more explicit that both of the above cases.

Comment: can't use java.time.Duration because I also need to store the original units in which the duration value was displayed (it is scraped from a UI)

Comment: Although, to be fair, it's trivial in Typescript to add when needed the appropriate annotation that `parseDurationInMilliseconds` returns a `number`, or that `plusToSeconds` is supposed to be a `number`; either annotation would prevent compilation.

Comment: This is the answer to the question that was actually asked.  The other answers are off on tangents.

Comment: Stating that Java optimizes for code correctness might be a valid point, but it seems to me (programming lots of languages, recently a bit of java) that the language either fails or is extremely inefficient at doing so. Granted, Java is old and lots of stuff didn't exist back then, but there are modern alternatives that provide arguably better correctness checking, like Haskell (and dare I say? Rust or Go). All the unwieldyness of Java is unnecessary for this goal. -- And besides, this doesn't *at all* explain the culture, but Solomonoff revealed that the culture is BS anyway.

Comment: That sample doesn't demonstrate that type inference is the problem just that JavaScript's decision to allow implicit conversions in a dynamic language is stupid. Any sane dynamic language or statically touted language with type inferrence wouldn't allow this. As an example for both kinds: python would throw a runtime excepting, Haskell wouldn't compile.

Comment: @tomsmeding It's worth noting that this argument is especially silly because Haskell has been around for 5 years *longer* than Java. Java may have a type system, but it didn't even have state of the art correctness verification when it was released.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik You can't define a class that has properties for a `Duration` and the original units? (This might be a great use case for a tuple, but it can definitely be covered by a class.)

Comment: While there are some other answers which provide very good information and insight, this one gets my +1 because it actually addresses the specific question that was asked

Comment: "Java optimizes for compile-time error detection", well it is a compiled language, seems obvious, for the others options, I and others already showed there was others.

Comment: @jpmc26 seeing as I have to do my own parser anyway, what good would Iderive from storing a `Duration` compared to storing a millisecond value, as I do now? The other thing I store is an enum that us like TimeUnit but has one more value, so it is my own enum as Java does not allow extending enums.

Comment: “Java optimizes for compile-time error detection” — No. It *provides* it but, as others have noted, it certainly doesn’t optimise for it in any sense of the word. Furthermore, this argument is *completely unrelated* to OP’s question because other languages that *do* actually optimise for compile-time error detection have much more lightweight syntax for similar scenarios. The over-the-top verbosity of Java has exactly *nothing* to do with its compile-time verification.

Comment: I once saw it stated that the reason `Pair` doesn't exist in `java.util` is because a generic Pair class gives no context to what the first and second items actually are. They have no semantic meaning: they are just "first" and "second". Hence, it is supposed to be better to force people to declare a specific class to hold that data. I think I'm inclined to agree - `java.util.Pair` would get abused to all hell. Same with Triplet. [This is worth a read](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-March/003973.html)

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, this answer is completely nonsensical, though I suppose it’s emotionally appealing. I’m not sure why it has so many votes. Haskell (or perhaps even more significantly, Idris) optimizes far more for correctness than Java, and it has tuples with a lightweight syntax. What’s more, defining a data type is a one-liner, and you get everything the Java version would get. This answer is an excuse for poor language design and unnecessary verbosity, but it *sounds* good if you like Java and aren’t familiar with other languages.

Comment: @Michael I've heard that argument a lot, but I don't buy it. Most of the time you'd use a pair the fact that the class **is** "just a pair of X and Y" is exactly what you want to say and `Pair<X, Y>` says that much better than `XAndY` (and says it to the compiler, too). It's the very abstract parametric polymorphic ("generic" in Java speak) structures and functions that give you non-fragile code-reuse and types getting much closer to enforcing actual correctness. Nobody suggests that everybody should implement their own special `List` class for each use case; why is `Pair` any different?

Comment: @Michael Yes there's a strong case to be made for presenting your interface to client code in terms of domain-specific concepts; so e.g. a `Name` class in a library dealing with people is much better to expose in your interface than a `Pair<String, String>`. But library internals *can* and should  use generic structures and algorithms, and `Pair` would be perfectly at home there. And sometimes the concept of a pair (of domain-specific things) really is what makes sense to expose in your interface, exactly as a method producing a `List<DomainSpecificThing>` would be fine.

Comment: -1 This answer is wrong. Java doesn't optimize for compile-time errors; it merely manages a clumsy try at it. As others have said, other languages which are older and leaner do it best, without being "heavy" and verbose like Java.

Comment: People saying that Java doesn't optimize for compile time error detection are missing important historical context: Java was the first *popular OO* language that offered a good degree of static type safety. Yes, Haskell or SML etc had better type systems, but they weren't object oriented, so IT managers thought they were too obscure. This was the 90s.  OO was the big buzzword.  Functional was scary and weird. For anyone interested in static guarantees for enterprise development, Java was basically the only option.

Comment: This answer is so misguided that I had to comment. Here's how you create a triple in ML: `(a, b, c)`. Here's how you create a record: `{f1: a, f2: b, f3: c}`. Both concise and 100% statically verifiable. Java's verbosity is not a deadly sin, but it is unnecessary. The example you provided against type inference uses a language that is well-known for its numerous design flaws - anything looks good by comparison to JavaScript (and yes I know that's actually TS, but it inherited many of JS's fundamental flaws).

Comment: You still need to unpack the triplet.  A bit of syntactic sugar to allow automatically doing that `(a,b,c) = methodReturningTriplet()` would be a game changer.

Comment: I'll try to answer some of the comments here. I know that some other languages are more concise, or better typed (or both). What I'm trying to express is that Java never *assumes* anything about the code (e.g.; You assigned a String to that field, so I'm just going to go ahead and assume that the type of this field is String), and *requires* the developer to state his intention at least once (eg: You are not allowed to assign a String to this field until you have *explicitly told me* that this field is meant to be a String). This philosophy requires a certain degree of verbosity.

Comment: @gardenhead Java's philosophy, in your case is that it must make sure that the values in the triplet are really of the type that the developer intended to put there. Which is a part that is missing from your example. So according to Java's design and philosophy, it is required that the developer states his intent by declaring the triplet return type. Such a method would necessarily be declared as `Triplet<A,B,C> doSomething()`. Creation of the actual triplet instance is simply `new Triplet(a,b,c)` or `triplet(a,b,c)` with static imports.

Comment: Java's verbosity isn't a philosophical position, it's a factor of historical accident and early-90s compiler performance. It probably peaked around Java 5 or 6 and has been [declining](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) [ever](https://www.oreilly.com/learning/java-8-functional-interfaces) [since](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/286).

Answer (score 50):

Java and Python are the two languages I use the most but I'm coming from the other direction.  That is, I was deep in the Java world before I started using Python so I might be able to help.  I think the answer to the larger question of "why are things so heavy" comes down to 2 things:

- The costs around development between the two are like the air in a long balloon animal balloon.  You can squeeze one part of the balloon and another part swells.  Python tends to squeeze the early part.  Java squeezes the later part.
- Java still lacks some features that would remove some of this weight.  Java 8 made a huge dent in this but the culture hasn't fully digested the changes.  Java could use a few more things such as `yield`.

Java 'optimizes' for high-value software that will be maintained for many years by large teams of people.  I've had the experience of writing stuff in Python and looking at it a year later and be baffled by my own code.  In Java I can look at tiny snippets of other people's code and instantly know what it does.  In Python you can't really do that.  It's not that one is better as you seem to realize, they just have different costs.

In the specific case you mention, there are no tuples.  The easy solution is to create a class with public values.  When Java first came out, people did this fairly regularly.  The first problem with doing that is that it's a maintenance headache.  If you need to add some logic or thread safety or want to use polymorphism, you will at the very least need to touch every class that interacts with that 'tuple-esque' object.  In Python there are solutions for this such as `__getattr__` etc. so it's not so dire.

There are some bad habits (IMO) around this though.  In this case if you want a tuple, I question why you would make it a mutable object.  You should only need getters (on a side note, I hate the get/set convention but it is what it is.)  I do think a bare class (mutable or not) can be useful in a private or package-private context in Java.  That is, by limiting the references in the project to the class, you can refactor later as needed without changing the public interface of the class.  Here's an example of how you can create a simple immutable object:

```
public class Blah 
{
  public static Blah blah(long number, boolean isInSeconds, boolean lessThanOneMillis)
  {
    return new Blah(number, isInSeconds, lessThanOneMillis);
  }

  private final long number;
  private final boolean isInSeconds;
  private final boolean lessThanOneMillis;

  public Blah(long number, boolean isInSeconds, boolean lessThanOneMillis)
  {
    this.number = number;
    this.isInSeconds = isInSeconds;
    this.lessThanOneMillis = lessThanOneMillis;
  }

  public long getNumber()
  {
    return number;
  }

  public boolean isInSeconds()
  {
    return isInSeconds;
  }

  public boolean isLessThanOneMillis()
  {
    return lessThanOneMillis;
  }
}
```

This is a kind of pattern I use.  If you aren't using an IDE, you should start.  It will generate the getters (and setters if you need them) for you so this isn't so painful.

I would feel remiss if I didn't point out that there is already a type that would appear to meet most of your needs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).  Setting that aside, the approach you are using is not well suited to Java as it plays to it's weaknesses, not it's strengths.  Here's a simple improvement:

```
public class Blah 
{
  public static Blah fromSeconds(long number)
  {
    return new Blah(number * 1000_000);
  }

  public static Blah fromMills(long number)
  {
    return new Blah(number * 1000);
  }

  public static Blah fromNanos(long number)
  {
    return new Blah(number);
  }

  private final long nanos;

  private Blah(long nanos)
  {
    this.nanos = nanos;
  }

  public long getNanos()
  {
    return nanos;
  }

  public long getMillis()
  {
    return getNanos() / 1000; // or round, whatever your logic is
  }

  public long getSeconds()
  {
    return getMillis() / 1000; // or round, whatever your logic is
  }

  /* I don't really know what this is about but I hope you get the idea */
  public boolean isLessThanOneMillis()
  {
    return getMillis() < 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57855/discussion-on-answer-by-jimmyjames-grokking-java-culture-why-are-things-so-hea).

Comment: May I suggest you also look at Scala with respect to "more modern" Java features ...

Comment: @MikeW I actually started with Scala way back in the early releases and was active on the scala forums for a while. I think it's a great achievement in language design but I came to the conclusion that is wasn't really what I was looking for and that I was a square peg in that community. I should look at it again because it's probably changed significantly since that time.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the approximate value aspect raised by the OP.

Comment: @ErikE The words "approximate value" don't appear in the question text.  If you can point me to the specific part of the question I didn't address, I can attempt to do so.

Comment: The concept of approximate value is present in the idea of margin of error. If a value has a margin of error, it is no longer precise, but approximate. Read the linked question, then see the selected answer and the comments by the OP about his final chosen implementation, and you'll see that the struggle causing him to post about "heavy Java culture" came at least in part from not having a clear concept of what OOP is about and how ApproximateDuration was worthy of being a domain-level concept. While this question didn't draw out this aspect much, the link has always been there.

Comment: @ErikE The question here is separate from the other question.  The code was copied from that one for laziness and to make it relevant but the point of the code examples is to demonstrate technique, not solve a specific problem completely.

Comment: But that ignores the fundamental reason why the OP thought Java was so heavy in the first place. The two questions are inextricably linked, and the moment you put code in it you are accepting that you're giving good advice for code. Only, you're continuing the primitive obsession pattern. How is that explaining why Java code is heavy, when it's a code smell that shouldn't be in any OOP code, not just Java? Java isn't heavy for that reason.

Comment: @ErikE Sorry, I disagree.  Referencing another question doesn't make it part of this question.  The first example shows how to create a immutable object in Java.  The second is a incremental improvement.  That's it.  You are reading into this too much.

Comment: That's fine! You're allowed to disagree. Thanks for engaging.

Comment: @ErikE I would provide a more precise answer but I think it's still a bit unclear what exactly what problem the OP is trying to solve, even considering the extra detail provided on your answer.  Without clear requirements, trying to solve a problem is a fool's errand, in my experience.  I do think your prognosis of the root error as "primitive obsessive" is correct.

Comment: I won't pretend I've never been misled by a bad question, but I seem to have a knack for reading between the lines and guessing people's root problems, and answering those.

Comment: @ErikE Sure, perhaps.  But in this case we are seeing the problem through a keyhole.  If you saw the bigger picture, you might have a completely different answer.  It's basically impossible to know whether you have given a "good answer" in this case.  I choose not to try attempt that and be direct about what I can provide.  If you want, I can provide a Java version example to your answer as an edit.

Comment: That would be much appreciated! You're right about the possible keyhole view. For now it's all we can do.

Answer (score 41):

Before you get too mad at Java, please read [my answer in your other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43647554/57611).

One of your complaints is the need to create a class just to return some set of values as an answer. This is a valid concern that I think shows your programming intuitions are right on track! However, I think other answers are missing the mark by sticking with the primitive obsession anti-pattern that you've committed to. And Java doesn't have the same ease of working with multiple primitives as Python has, where you can return multiple values natively and assign them to multiple variables easily.

But once you start thinking about what an `ApproximateDuration` type does for you, you realize that it's not scoped so narrowly to "just a seemingly needless class in order to return three values". The concept represented by this class is actually one of your **core domain business concepts**—the need to be able to represent times in an approximate way, and compare them. This needs to be part of the ubiquitous language of the core of your application, with good object and domain support for it, so that it can be tested, modular, reusable, and useful.

Is your code that sums approximate durations together  (or durations with a margin of error, however you represent that) wholly procedural or is there any object-ness to it? I would propose that good design around summing approximate durations together would dictate doing it outside of any consuming code, within a class that itself can be tested. I think using this kind of domain object will have a positive ripple effect in your code that helps steer you away from line-by-line procedural steps to accomplish a single high-level task (though with many responsibilities), toward single-responsibility classes that are free from the conflicts of differing concerns.

For example, let's say that you learn more about what precision or scale is actually required for your duration summing and comparison to work correctly, and you find out that you need an intermediate flag to indicate "approximately 32 milliseconds error" (close to the square root of 1000, so halfway logarithmically between 1 and 1000). If you've bound yourself to code that uses primitives to represent this, you'll have to find every place in the code where you have `is_in_seconds,is_under_1ms` and change it to `is_in_seconds,is_about_32_ms,is_under_1ms`. Everything would have to change all over the place! Making a class whose responsibility is to record the margin of error so that it can be consumed elsewhere frees your consumers from knowing details of what margins of error matter or anything about how they combine, and lets them just specify the margin of error that is relevant at the moment. (That is, no consuming code whose margin of error is correct is forced to change when you add a new margin of error level in the class, since all the old margins of error are still valid).

**Closing Statement**

The complaint about Java's heaviness then seems to go away as you move closer to the principles of SOLID and GRASP, and more advanced software engineering.

**Addendum**

I will add completely gratuitously and unfairly that C#'s automatic properties and ability to assign get-only properties in constructors helps clean up even further the somewhat messy code that "the Java way" will require (with explicit private backing fields and getter/setter functions):

```csharp
// Warning: C# code!
public sealed class ApproximateDuration {
   public ApproximateDuration(int lowMilliseconds, int highMilliseconds) {
      LowMilliseconds = lowMilliseconds;
      HighMilliseconds = highMilliseconds;
   }
   public int LowMilliseconds { get; }
   public int HighMilliseconds { get; }
}
```

Here is a Java implementation of the above:

```java
public final class ApproximateDuration {
  private final int lowMilliseconds;
  private final int highMilliseconds;

  public ApproximateDuration(int lowMilliseconds, int highMilliseconds) {
    this.lowMilliseconds = lowMilliseconds;
    this.highMilliseconds = highMilliseconds;
  }

  public int getLowMilliseconds() {
    return lowMilliseconds;
  }

  public int getHighMilliseconds() {
    return highMilliseconds;
  }
}
```

Now that is pretty darn clean. Note the very important and intentional use of immutability--this seems crucial for this particular kind of value-bearing class.

For that matter, this class is also a decent candidate for being a `struct`, a value type. Some testing will show whether switching to a struct has a run-time performance benefit (it could).

Comment: I think this is my favourite answer. I find that when I promote a crappy throwaway holder class like this into something grown-up, it becomes the home for all the related responsibilities, and zing! everything gets cleaner! And I usually learn something interesting about the problem space at the same time. Obviously there's a skill in avoiding over-engineering ... but Gosling wasn't stupid when he left out tuple syntax, same as with GOTOs. Your closing statement is excellent. Thanks!

Comment: If you like this answer, read up on Domain-Driven Design. It has a lot to say on this topic of representing domain concepts in code.

Comment: @neontapir Yep, thanks! I knew there was a name for it! :-) Though I must say that I prefer it when a domain concept appears organically from an inspired bit of refactoring (like this!)... it's a bit like when you get to fix your 19th century gravity problem by discovering Neptune...

Comment: @SusanW I agree. Refactoring to remove primitive obsession can be an excellent way to uncover domain concepts!

Comment: I added a Java version of the example as discussed.  I'm not up on all the magic syntactical sugar in C# so if there's something missing, let me know.

Answer (score 24):

Both Python and Java are optimized for maintainability according to the philosophy of their designers, but they have very different ideas about how to achieve this.

Python is a multi-paradigm language which optimizes for **clarity** and **simplicity** of code (easy to read and write).

Java is (traditionally) a single-paradigm class-based OO language which optimizes for **explicitness** and **consistency** - even at the cost of more verbose code.

A Python tuple is a data structure with a fixed number of fields. The same functionality can be achieved by a regular class with explicitly declared fields. In Python it is natural to provide tuples as alternative to classes because it allows you to simplify code greatly, especially due to the built-in syntax support for tuples.

But this does not really match the Java culture to provide such shortcuts, since you can already use explicit declared classes. No need to introduce a different kind of data structure just to save some lines of code and avoid some declarations.

Java prefers a single concept (classes) consistently applied with a minimum of special-case syntactic sugar, while Python provides multiple tools and lots of syntactic sugar to allow you to chose the most convenient for any particular purpose.

Comment: +1, but how does this mesh with statically typed languages with classes, such as Scala, which nevertheless found the need to introduce tuples? I think tuples are just the neater solution in some cases, even for languages with classes.

Comment: @AndresF.: What do you mean by mesh? Scala is a language distinct from Java and have different design principles and idioms.

Comment: I meant it in reply to your 5th paragraph, which starts with "but this does not really match the Java culture [...]". Indeed, I agree verbosity is part of Java's culture, but lack of tuples can't be because they "already use explicitly declared classes" -- after all, Scala also has explicit classes (and introduces the more concise *case classes*), but it also allows tuples! In the end, I think it's likely Java didn't introduce tuples not only because classes can achieve the same (with more clutter), but also because its syntax must be familiar to C programmers, and C didn't have tuples.

Comment: @AndresF.: Scala does not have an aversion against multiple ways of doing things, it combines features from both functional paradigm and from  classical OO. It is closer to Python philosophy in that way.

Comment: @AndresF.: Yes Java started out with syntax close to C/C++, but simplified a lot. C# started out as an almost exact copy of of Java, but have added a lot of features over the years including tuples. So it is really a difference in language design philosophy. (Later versions of Java is seem be less dogmatic though. Higher-order function were initially rejected because you could do the same which classes, but now they have been introduced. So maybe we are seeing a change in philosophy.)

Comment: Oh, I agree it's part of Java's philosophy. I agree with your overall answer (hence my +1), but I believe there's no single technical issue in Java (be it explicit classes or whatnot) that would lead to this decision. Other languages with a similar starting feature set, such as Scala or C#, went a different way. So yes, it's a matter of philosophical choices indeed, but no, they aren't tied to specific technical aspects (such as being class based). Much of what Java chose not to do can be added to Java without much fuss -- but they chose not to.

Comment: @AndresF ... You're right. This isn't about the technical features of Java. It's just that Java happened at the right time and provided the right mix of feature to become the de facto standard enterprise language. The whole cultural issue here had nothing to do with what Java can or can't do. It's about what developers working on large enterprise systems need in their code base. It's about optimizing for working on a system which is too large for any single developer to fully understand.

Answer (score 16):

Don't search for practices; it is usually a bad idea, as said in *[Best practices BAD, patterns GOOD?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/best-practices-bad-patterns-good)*. I know you're not asking for best practices, but I still think you will find some relevant elements in there.

Searching for a solution to your problem is better than a practice, and your problem is no tuple to return three values in Java fast:

- There are Arrays
- You can return an array as a list in a one-liner: Arrays.asList(...)
- If you want to keep the object side with the less boilerplate possible (and no lombok):

---

```
class MyTuple {
    public final long value_in_milliseconds;
    public final boolean is_in_seconds;
    public final boolean is_under_1ms;
    public MyTuple(long value_in_milliseconds,....){
        ...
    }
 }
```

Here you have an immutable object containing just your data, and public so there is no need for getters. Note that however if you use some serialization tools or persistence layer like an ORM, they commonly use getter/setter (and may accept a parameter to use fields instead of getter/setter). And this is why these practices are used a lot. So if you want to know about practices, it's better to understand why they're here for a better usage of them.

Finally: I use getters because I use a lot of serialisation tools, but I don't write them neither; I use lombok: I use the shortcuts provided by my IDE.

Comment: There is still value in understanding common idioms you come across in various languages, as they become a more accessible de facto standard.  Those idioms tend to fall under the heading of "best practices" for whatever reason.

Comment: And in Python, one line: `MyTuple = namedtuple('MyTuple', 'value_in_milliseconds is_in_seconds is_under_1ms')`

Comment: Hey, a sensible solution to the problem. It seems quite reasonable to just write a class (/struct) with a few public members instead of a full-blown over-engineered OOP solution with [gs]etters.

Comment: Actually, I now use this as the solution to the original issue, thanks. (Except I have put the parser into the constructor). I did not realize "final" allowed initialization in the constructor. And now I have a compact solution that is object-oriented, is properly immutable, and does not have the bloat associated with getters and setters. I did change the two fields, is_in_seconds and is_under_1ms, to one originalTimeUnit field, and the value is an enum of UNDER1MS, MILLISECONDS, SECONDS; this way allows adding minutes if they come up later.

Comment: And I think I am starting to grok this after all. There is a concentration on proper OOP, there are standard patterns that have evolved over decades, people learn that the patterns are maintainable and so on, and so they use them at all times.

Comment: This does lead to bloat because, unlike Python, the search or a shorter and more elegant solution is not encouraged. But the upside is that the bloat will be more or less the same kind for any Java developer. Therefore there is a degree of higher maintainability because developers are more interchangeable, and if two projects get joined or two teams unintentionally diverge, there is less style difference to fight.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik It's a trade-off between YAGNI and OOP. Orthodox OOP says that every single object should be replaceable; the only thing that matters is the object's public interface. This allows you to write code that's less focused on concrete objects, and more on interfaces; and since fields cannot be parts of an interface, you never expose them. This *can* make code much easier to maintain in the long run. Additionaly, it allows you to prevent invalid states. In your original sample, it's possible to have an object that's both "<ms" and "s", which are mutually exclusive. That's bad.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik I disagree with your statement, first because shorter and more elegant aren't always corrolated. In every language we are always encouraged to producde readable and maintenable code. All one-liner aren't so easy to read and maintain, and the opposite is obviously true. That's why tuple is discouraged, it's almost no better than return an Array.

Comment: What is this "lombok" you speak of?

Comment: @Luaan That trade-off only exists in Java because of its limitations. If you look at properties in C# or how fields in Python work you can see that it's quite simple to allow simple code without lots of boilerplate that still allows easy extension when it actually becomes necessary.

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's a Java library which does a lot of fairly unrelated things. It's very good though. [Here are the features](https://projectlombok.org/features/index.html)

Answer (score 11):

About Java idioms in general:

There are various reasons why Java has classes for everything. As far as my knowledge goes, the main reason is:

Java should be easy to learn for beginners. The more explicit things are, the harder it is to miss important details. Less magic happens that would be hard for beginners to grasp.

---

As to your specific example: the line of argument for a separate class is this: if those three things are strongly-enough related to each other that they are returned as one value, its worth naming that "thing". And introducing a name for a group of things that are structured in a common way means defining a class.

You can reduce the boilerplate with tools like Lombok:

```
@Value
class MyTuple {
    long value_in_milliseconds;
    boolean is_in_seconds;
    boolean is_under_1ms;
}
```

Comment: The is also Google's AutoValue project:  https://github.com/google/auto/blob/master/value/userguide/index.md

Comment: This is also why Java programs can be relatively easily _maintained!_

Answer (score 7):

There are lots of things that could be said about the Java culture, but I think that in the case you're confronted with right now, there are a few significant aspects:

1. Library code is written once but used much more often.  While it's nice to minimize the overhead of writing the library, it's probably more worthwhile in the long run to write in a way that minimizes the overhead of using the library.
2. That means that self-documenting types are great: method names help make it clear what's happening and what you're getting out of an object.
3. Static typing is a very useful tool for eliminating certain classes of errors.  It certainly doesn't fix everything (people like to joke about Haskell that once you get the type system to accept your code, it's probably correct), but it  makes it very easy to make certain kinds of wrong things impossible.
4. Writing library code is about specifying contracts.  Defining interfaces for your argument and result types makes the boundaries of your contracts more clearly defined.  If something accepts or produces a tuple, there's no saying whether it's the kind of tuple you should actually receive or produce, and there's very little in the way of constraints on such a generic type (does it even have the right number of elements? are they of the type that you were expecting?).

### "Struct" classes with fields

As other answers have mentioned, you can just use a class with public fields.  If you make these final, then you get an immutable class, and you'd initialize them with the constructor:

```
   class ParseResult0 {
      public final long millis;
      public final boolean isSeconds;
      public final boolean isLessThanOneMilli;

      public ParseResult0(long millis, boolean isSeconds, boolean isLessThanOneMilli) {
         this.millis = millis;
         this.isSeconds = isSeconds;
         this.isLessThanOneMilli = isLessThanOneMilli;
      }
   }
```

Of course, this means that you're tied to a particular class, and anything that ever needs to produce or consume a parse result has to use this class.  For some applications, that's fine.  For others, that can cause some pain.  Much Java code is about defining contracts, and that will typically take you into interfaces.

Another pitfall is that with a class based approach, you're exposing fields and all of those fields *must* have values.  E.g., isSeconds and millis always have to have some value, even if isLessThanOneMilli is true.  What should the interpretation of the value of the millis field be when isLessThanOneMilli is true?

### "Structures" as Interfaces

With the static methods allowed in interfaces, it's actually relatively easy to create immutable types without a whole lot of syntactic overhead.  For instance, I  might implement the kind of result structure you're talking about as something like this:

```
   interface ParseResult {
      long getMillis();

      boolean isSeconds();

      boolean isLessThanOneMilli();

      static ParseResult from(long millis, boolean isSeconds, boolean isLessThanOneMill) {
         return new ParseResult() {
            @Override
            public boolean isSeconds() {
               return isSeconds;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isLessThanOneMilli() {
               return isLessThanOneMill;
            }

            @Override
            public long getMillis() {
               return millis;
            }
         };
      }
   }
```

That's still a lot of boilerplate, I absolutely agree, but there are a couple of benefits, too, and I think those get start to answer some of your main questions.

With a structure like this parse result, the *contract* of your parser is very clearly defined.  In Python, one tuple isn't really distinct from another tuple.  In Java, static typing is available, so we already rule out certain classes of errors.  For instance, if you're returning a tuple in Python, and you want to return the tuple (millis, isSeconds, isLessThanOneMilli), you can accidentally do:

```
return (true, 500, false)
```

when you meant:

```
return (500, true, false)
```

With this kind of Java interface, you can't compile:

```
return ParseResult.from(true, 500, false);
```

at all.  You have to do:

```
return ParseResult.from(500, true, false);
```

That's a benefit of statically typed languages in general.

This approach also starts to give you the ability to restrict what values you can get.  For instance, when calling getMillis(), you could check whether isLessThanOneMilli() is true, and if it is, throw an IllegalStateException (for instance), since there's no meaningful value of millis in that case.

### Making it Hard to Do the Wrong Thing

In the interface example above, you still have the problem that you could accidentally swap the isSeconds and isLessThanOneMilli arguments, though, since they have the same type.

In practice, you really might want to make use of TimeUnit and duration, so that you'd have a result like:

```
   interface Duration {
      TimeUnit getTimeUnit();

      long getDuration();

      static Duration from(TimeUnit unit, long duration) {
         return new Duration() {
            @Override
            public TimeUnit getTimeUnit() {
               return unit;
            }

            @Override
            public long getDuration() {
               return duration;
            }
         };
      }
   }

   interface ParseResult2 {

      boolean isLessThanOneMilli();

      Duration getDuration();

      static ParseResult2 from(TimeUnit unit, long duration) {
         Duration d = Duration.from(unit, duration);
         return new ParseResult2() {
            @Override
            public boolean isLessThanOneMilli() {
               return false;
            }

            @Override
            public Duration getDuration() {
               return d;
            }
         };
      }

      static ParseResult2 lessThanOneMilli() {
         return new ParseResult2() {
            @Override
            public boolean isLessThanOneMilli() {
               return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Duration getDuration() {
               throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
         };
      }
   }
```

That's getting to be a *lot* more code, but you only need to write it once, and (assuming you've properly documented things), the people who end up *using* your code don't have to guess at what the result means, and can't accidentally do things like `result[0]` when they mean `result[1]`.  You still get to *create* instances pretty succinctly, and getting data out of them isn't all that hard either:

```
  ParseResult2 x = ParseResult2.from(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 32);
  ParseResult2 y = ParseResult2.lessThanOneMilli();
```

Note that you could actually do something like this with the class based approach, too. Just specify constructors for the different cases.  You still have the issue of what to initialize the other fields to, though, and you can't prevent access to them.

Another answer mentioned that the enterprise-type nature of Java means that much of the time, you're composing other libraries that already exist, or writing libraries for other people to use. Your *public API* shouldn't require lots of time consulting the documentation to decipher result types if it can be avoided.

You only *write* these structures once, but you *create* them many times, so you still do want that concise creation (which you get). The static typing makes sure that the data you're getting out of them is what you expect.

Now, all that said, there are still places where simple tuples or lists can make a lot of sense. There may be less overhead in returning an array of something, and if that's the case (and that overhead is significant, which you'd determine with profiling), then using a simple array of values *internally* may make lots of sense.  Your public API should still probably have clearly defined types.

Comment: I've used my own enum instead of TimeUnit at the end, because I just added UNDER1MS along with actual time units. So now I just have two fields, not three. (In theory, I could misuse TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS, but that would be very confusing.)

Comment: I did not create a getter, but now I do see how a getter would allow me to throw an exception if, with `originalTimeUnit=DurationTimeUnit.UNDER1MS` , the caller tried to read the milliseconds value.

Comment: I know you've mentioned it, but remember your example with python tuples is really about dynamic vs statically typed tuples; it doesn't really say much about tuples themselves. You *can* have statically typed tuples which will fail to compile, as I'm sure you know :)

Comment: "Library code is written once but used much more often." → If code reuse is a thing, and Java people certainly seem to think it is, then *almost all* code is library code. You're optimizing for a case that simply doesn't exist.

Comment: @Veedrac I'm not sure what you mean.  My point was that it's OK to write library code more verbosely like this (even though it takes longer), since there will be spent more time *using* the code than *writing* it.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor How do you expect to *use* code without *writing* code?

Comment: @Veedrac Yes, that's true. But I'd maintain that there *is* a distinction between code that will be meaningfully reused, and code that won't. E.g., in a Java package, some of the classes are public, and get used from other locations.  Those APIs should be well thought out. Internally, there are classes that may only need to talk to each other.  Those internal couplings are the places where quick and dirty structures (e.g,. an Object[] that's expected to have three elements) might be fine. For the public API, something more meaningful and explicit should usually be preferred.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I don't think that reflects a typical Java attitude, though. If returning `Object[]` from a function was considered legitimate, Java would have tuples to handle that case in a type-safe manner.

Comment: @Veedrac I agree there, too. I don't think that an Object[] is great anywhere, but *if* it's going to show up, it should probably be in some internal details somewhere; not in a public API.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that you compare **apples to oranges**. You asked how to simulate returning more than single value giving a quick&dirty python example with untyped tuple and you actually received the practically [one-liner answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43634160/5479362).

The accepted answer provides a correct business solution. No quick temporary workaround which you would have to throw away and implement correctly first time you'd need to do anything practical with the returned value, but a POJO class that is compatibile with a large set of libraries, including persistance, serialization/deserialization, instrumentation and anything possible.

This is also not long at all. The only thing you need to write are the field definitions. Setters, getters, hashCode and equals can be generated. So your actual question should be, why the getters and setters are not auto-generated but it's a syntax issue (syntactic sugar issue, would some say) and not the cultural issue.

And finally, you're **overthinking** trying to speed up something that's not important at all. The time spent writing DTO classes is insignificant compared to time spent maintaining and debugging the system. Therefore nobody optimizes for less verbosity.

Comment: "Nobody" is factually incorrect - there are loads of tools that optimize for less verbosity, regular expressions are an extreme example. But you might have meant "nobody in the mainstream Java world", and in that reading the answer makes a lot of sense, thanks. My own concern with verbosity is not the time spent writing code but the time spent reading it; the IDE won't save reading time; but it seems the idea is that 99% of the times one only reads the interface definition so THAT should be concise?

Answer (score 5):

The are three different factors that contribute to what you are observing.

### Tuples versus named fields

Perhaps the most trivial - in the other languages you used a tuple. Debating whether tuples is a good idea is not really the point - but in Java you did use a heavier structure so it's a slightly unfair comparison: you could have used an array of objects and some type casting.

### Language syntax

Could it be easier to declare the class? I'm not talking about making the fields public or using a map but something like Scala's case classes, which provide all the benefits of the setup you described but much more concise:

```
case class Foo(duration: Int, unit: String, tooShort: Boolean)
```

We could have that - but there's a cost: the syntax becomes more complicated. Of course it might be worth it for some cases, or even for most cases, or even for most cases for the next 5 years - but it needs to be judged. By the way, this is on of the nice things with languages you can modify yourself (i.e. lisp) - and note how this becomes possible due to the simplicity of syntax. Even if you don't actually modify the language, a simple syntax enables more powerful tools; for example a lot of times I miss some refactoring options available for Java but not for Scala.

### Language philosophy

But the most important factor is that a language should enable a certain way of thinking. Sometimes it might feel oppressive (I've often wished for support for a certain feature) but removing features is just as important as having them. Could you support everything? Sure, but then you might as well just write a compiler that compiles every single language. In other words, you won't have a language - you'll have a superset of languages and every project would basically adopt a subset.

It is of course possible to write code that goes against the language's philosophy, and, as you observed, the results are often ugly. Having a class with just a couple of fields in Java is akin to using a var in Scala, degenerating prolog predicates to functions, doing an unsafePerformIO in haskell etc. Java classes are not meant to be light - they are not there to pass data around. When something seems hard, it's often fruitful to step back and see if there's another way. In your example:

Why have the duration separate from the units? There are plenty of time libraries that let you declare a duration - something like Duration(5, seconds) (syntax will vary), which will then let you do whatever you want in a far more robust way. Maybe you want to convert it - why check if result[1] (or [2]?) is a 'hour' and multiplying by 3600? And for the third argument - what's its purpose? I'd guess that at some point you'll have to print "less than 1ms" or the actual time - that's some logic that naturally belongs with the time data. I.e. you should have a class like this:

```
class TimeResult {
    public TimeResult(duration, unit, tooShort)
    public String getResult() {
        if tooShort:
           return "too short"
        else:
           return format(duration)
}
```

}

or whatever you actually want to do with the data, hence encapsulating the logic.

Of course, there might be a case where this way won't work - I'm not saying that this is the magic algorithm for converting tuple results to idiomatic Java code! And there might be cases where it's very ugly and bad and perhaps you should have used a different language - that's why there are so many after all!

But my view on why classes are "heavy structures" in Java is that you are not meant to use them as data containers but as self-contained cells of logic.

Comment: What I want to *do* with the durations is actually about making a sum of them and then comparing to another. No output involved. The comparison needs to take rounding into account, so I need to know the original time units at the time of the comparison.

Comment: It would probably be possible to create a way of adding and comparing instances of my class, but this could get hugely heavy. Especially since I also need to divide and multiply by floats (there are percentages to verify in that UI). So for now I made an immutable class with final fields, which looks like a nice compromise.

Comment: The more important part about this particular question was the more general side of things, and from all the answers a picture seems to be coming together.

Comment: @MikhailRamendik perhaps some sort of an accumulator would be an option - but you know the problem better. Indeed it's not about solving this particular issue, sorry if I got a bit sidetracked - my main point is that the language discourages the use of "simple" data. sometimes, this helps you rethink your approach - other times an int is just an int

Comment: @MikhailRamendik The nice thing about the boilerplatey way is that once you have a class, you can add behavior to it. And/or make it immutable as you did (this is a good idea most of the time; you can always return a new object as the sum). In the end, your "superfluous" class may encapsulate all the behavior you need and then the cost for the getters gets negligible. Moreover, you may or may not need them. Consider using [lombok](https://projectlombok.org) or [autovalue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value).

Answer (score 5):

To my understanding, the core reasons are

1. Interfaces are the basic Java way to abstract away classes.
2. Java can only return a single value from a method - an object or an array or a native value (int/long/double/float/boolean).
3. Interfaces cannot contain fields, only methods.  If you want to access a field, you must go through a method - hence getters and setters.
4. If an method returns an interface, you must have an implementing class to actually return.

This gives you the "You must write a class to return for any non-trivial result" which in turn is rather heavy.  If you used a class instead of the interface you could just have fields and use them directly, but that tie you to a specific implementation.

Comment: To add to this: *if* you *only* need this in a small context (say, a private method in a class), it's fine to use a bare record - ideally immutable. But it really really really shouldn't ever leak into the public contract of the class (or even worse, the library!). You may decide against records simply to ensure that this never happens with future code changes, of course; it's often the simpler solution.

Comment: And I agree with the "Tuples do not work well in Java"-view.  If you use generics this will very quickly end up nasty.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen They work pretty well in Scala, a statically typed language with generics *and* tuples. So maybe this is Java's fault?

Comment: @AndresF. Please note the "If you use generics"-part.  The way Java does this does not lend itself to complex constructions as opposed to e.g. Haskell.   I do not know Scala well enough to do a comparison, but is it true that Scala allows for multiple return values?  That might help quite a lot.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Scala functions have a single return value which may be of a tuple type (e.g. `def f(...): (Int, Int)` is a function `f` which returns a value which happens to be a tuple of integers). I'm not sure generics in Java are the problem with it; do note that Haskell also does type erasure, for example. I don't think there is a *technical* reason why Java doesn't have tuples.

Comment: @AndresF. There is no technical reason that Java doesn't have lots of things.  It is always a matter of deciding what goes in a language and what doesn't.   You can return a tuple as an Object[] - you just don't get generics.  The Word Of God is that _in actual usage_ the generic tend to explode - my guess is that the language does not help unpack return values (like e.g. Perl does).   So, you cannot blame it on the language, but you can disagree with the decisions of the architects.   They got something right as Java can be used to build _very_ big things!

Answer (score 3):

I agree with JacquesB answer that

> Java is (traditionally) a single-paradigm class-based OO language
>   which optimizes for explicitness and consistency

But explicitness and consistency are not the end goals to optimize for. When you say 'python is optimized for readability', you immediately mention that the end goal is 'maintainability' and 'development speed'.

What do you achieve when you have explicitness and consistency, done Java way? My take is that it's evolved as a language that claims to provide predictable, consistent, uniform way to solve any software problem.

In other words, Java culture is optimized for making managers believe that they understand software development.

Or, as [one wise guy put it a very long time ago](http://www.stlport.org/resources/StepanovUSA.html),

> The best way to judge a language is to look at the code written by its
>   proponents. "Radix enim omnium malorum est cupiditas" - and Java is
>   clearly an example of a money oriented programming (MOP). As the chief
>   proponent of Java at SGI told me: "Alex, you have to go where the
>   money is." But I do not particularly want to go where the money is -
>   it usually does not smell nice there.

Answer (score 3):

*(This answer is not an explanation for Java in particular, but instead addresses the general question of “What might [heavy] practices optimize for?”)*

Consider these two principles:

1. It's good when your program does the right thing. We should make it easy to write programs that do the right thing.
2. It's bad when your program does the wrong thing. We should make it harder to write programs that do the wrong thing.

Trying to optimize one of these goals may sometimes get in the way of the other (i.e. **making it harder to do the wrong thing may also make it harder to do the right thing**, or vice-versa).

Which tradeoffs are made in any particular case depends on the application, the decisions of the programmers or team in question, and the culture (of the organization or language community).

For example, if a bug or a few hours' outage in your program could result in loss of lives (medical systems, aeronautics) or even merely money (like millions of dollars in say Google's ads systems), you would make different tradeoffs (not just in your language but also in other aspects of engineering culture) than you would for a one-off script: it is likely lean towards the "heavy" side.

Other examples that tend to make your system more "heavy":

- When you have a large codebase worked on by many teams over many years, one big concern is that someone may use someone else's API incorrectly. A function getting called with arguments in the wrong order, or being called without ensuring some preconditions/constraints that it expects, could be catastrophic.
- As a special case of this, say your team maintains a particular API or library, and would like to change or refactor it. The more “constrained” your users are in how they could be using your code, the easier it is to change it. (Note that it would be preferable here to have actual guarantees here that no one could be using it in an unusual way.)
- If the development is split among multiple people or teams, it might seem a good idea to have one person or team “specify” the interface, and have others actually implement it. For it to work, you need to be able to gain a degree of confidence when the implementation is done, that the implementation actually matches the specification.

These are just some examples, to give you an idea of cases where making things “heavy” (and making it harder for you to just write out some code quickly) may genuinely be intentional. (One might even argue that if writing code requires a lot of effort, it may lead you to think more carefully before writing code! Of course this line of argument quickly gets ridiculous.)

An example: Google's internal Python system tends to make things “heavy” such that you cannot simply import someone else's code, you have to declare the dependency in a [BUILD file](https://bazel.build/), the team whose code you want to import need to have their library declared as visible to your code, etc.

---

**Note**: All the above is just about when things tend to get "heavy". I absolutely do **not** claim that Java or Python (either the languages themselves, or their cultures) make optimum tradeoffs for any particular case; that's for you to think about. Two related links on such tradeoffs:

- a great post by Erik Osheim on [What is the appeal of dynamically-typed languages?](https://gist.github.com/non/ec48b0a7343db8291b92) — it goes in the opposite direction, of trying to explain why someone may prefer a language like Python.
- [answer on this site by user Newtopian](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/63145/3220) to *Differences between “Java OOP” and “Pythonic OOP”?*

Comment: What about *reading* code? There's another tradeoff there. Code weighted down by bizarre incantantions and profuse rituals is harder to read; with boilerplate and needless text (and class hierarchies!) in your IDE, it becomes harder to see what the code is actually doing. I can see the argument that code should not necessarily be easy to write (not sure if I agree with it, but it has some merit), but it should definitely be easy to *read*. Obviously complex code can and has been built with Java -- it'd be foolish to claim otherwise -- but was it *thanks* to its verbosity, or in *spite* of it?

Comment: @AndresF. I edited the answer to make it clearer it's not about Java specifically (of which I'm not a great fan). But yes, tradeoffs when reading code: at one end you want to be able to easily read “what the code is actually doing” as you said. At the other end, you want to be able to easily see answers to questions like: how does this code relate to other code? What's the worst this code could do: what can its impact be on other state, what are its side effects? What external factors could this code possibly depend on? (Of course ideally we want quick answers to both sets of questions.)

Answer (score 2):

The Java culture has evolved over time with heavy influences from both open source and enterprise software backgrounds--which is a strange mix if you really think about it.  Enterprise solutions demand heavy tools, and open source demands simplicity.  The end result is that Java is somewhere in the middle.

Part of what is influencing the recommendation is what is considered readable and maintainable in Python and Java is very different.

- In Python, the tuple is a *language* feature.
- In both Java and C#, the tuple is (or would be) a *library* feature.

I only mention C# because the standard library has a set of Tuple<A,B,C,..n> classes, and it's a perfect example of how unwieldy tuples are if the language doesn't support them directly.  In almost every instance, your code becomes more readable and maintainable if you have well chosen classes to handle the issue.  In the specific example in your linked Stack Overflow question, the other values would be easily expressed as calculated getters on the return object.

An interesting solution that the C# platform did which provides a happy middle ground is the idea of [anonymous objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx) (released in [C# 3.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308966.aspx)) which scratch this itch quite well.  Unfortunately, Java doesn't have an equivalent yet.

Until Java's language features are amended, the most readable and maintainable solution is to have a dedicated object.  That's due to constraints in the language that date back to it's beginnings in 1995.  The original authors had many more language features planned that never made it, and backwards compatibility is one of the main constraints surrounding Java's evolution over time.

Comment: In the latest version of c# the new tuples are first class citizens rather than library classes. It took too many versions to get there.

Comment: The last 3 paragraphs can be summarized as "Language X has the feature you seek that Java doesn't", and I fail to see what they add to the answer. Why mentioning C# in a Python to Java topic? Nope, I just don't see the point. A bit weird from a 20k+ rep guy.

Comment: As I said, "I only mention C# because Tuples are a library feature" similar to how that would work in Java if it had Tuples in the main library.  It's very unwieldy to use, and the better answer is almost always to have a dedicated class.  The anonymous objects do scratch a similar itch to what tuples are designed for, though.  Without language support for something better, you essentially have to work with what is most maintainable.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko, maybe there is hope for Java 9?  This is just one of those features that are the logical next step to lambdas.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I'm not sure that's quite true (first class citizens) - they seem to be syntax extensions to create and unwrap instances of classes from the library, rather having first class support in the CLR as class, struct, enum do.

Comment: .... 1) Of course it's syntax sugar. C# is just Java will all the sugar I wish Java had. 2. C# introduced pattern matching along with Tuples, so I'm not sure what you're all trying to get at.

Comment: @AndresF. There are many things that make tuples useful even if you don't have all the possible operators you've seen in other languages that use tuples. Tuples are convenient immutable records. Deconstruction is still a thing. Helper methods are still a thing. Lambda's that allow you to use generic methods on tuples are a thing (though in that case, anonymous types might be better). Even as fixed-size, per-element-typed pseudo-arrays (as in C# before version 7), they are useful.

Comment: @RubberDuck The *plans* for pattern matching in C# 7 were a lot more interesting than what actually made it through - but all the tools we have now are still great, and certainly make tuples very convenient. I'm just looking forward to the things that didn't make it yet :) C#'s pattern matching is nowhere near the capabilities of even F# yet - but they're getting better with every new version.

Comment: @PeteKirkham CLR != C#. F# has first-class tuples even though CLR doesn't. Sure, it sometimes leaks a bit, but that's true of pretty much everything (after all, x86 assembly doesn't have first-class support either, does it? :)). C#7's tuples are a lot different from the older versions, and we get a lot more ways to handle them in a nicer fashion; and more's to come. The same way, Scala has first-class tuples without JVM support.

Comment: @Luaan `(1, 2, 3)` is an instance of the library struct `ValueTuple<int,int,int>`, so saying that they are first class types rather that library classes is not quite right. They are first class language features implemented using library classes.

Comment: @PeteKirkham I guess that depends on what you call "first class". Are C# arrays first class objects? Are enums? `out` arguments? Lambda expressions?

Comment: @Luaan What do you mean "deconstruction", without pattern matching? That's what I meant by pattern matching. If you cannot do `(x, y, z) = f(...)` then tuples are useless, in my opinion. If you must do `t.x`, `t.y`, etc, that's pretty cumbersome and negates most of the benefits of tuples. For immutability you can just define an immutable class.

Comment: @AndresF. You can do exactly that. And even better, it's a general feature of the language, so you can make deconstruction for any type you want. `var (x, y) = point;` kind of stuff. The main limitation right now in C# is that it is a statement, not an expression - but that isn't that much of a problem in a primarily imperative language. But they're very useful even in the `t.x` scenario, because the members are (optionally) named, as well as statically typed - that makes them quite a bit more expressive than arrays. And unlike anonymous types, they can be used anywhere.

Comment: @Luaan Cool about C#, I didn't know this! But in this case, it has a form of pattern matching/deconstruction (which I simplistically called "pattern matching"), which makes its tuples useful. Without it, they would be far less useful. I stand by my initial assertion: without pattern matching, tuples aren't very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I think one of the core things about using a class in this case is that what goes together should stay together.

I've had this discussion the other way around, about method arguments:
Consider a simple method that calculates BMI:

```
CalculateBMI(weight,height)
{
  System.out.println("BMI: " + (( weight / height ) x 703));
}
```

In this case I would argue against this style because weight and height are related. The method "communicates" those are two separate values when they're not.
When would you calculate a BMI with the weight of one person and the height of another? It would not make sense.

```
CalculateBMI(Person)
{
  System.out.println("BMI: " + (( Person.weight / Person.height ) x 703));
}
```

Makes a lot more sense because now you clearly communicate that the height and weight come from the same source.

The same goes for returning multiple values. If they are clearly connected then return a neat little package and use an object, if they're not return multiple values.

Comment: Ok, but suppose you then have a (hypothetical) task to show a graph: how does BMI depend on weight for some particular fixed height. Then, you can't do that without creating a Person for each data point. And, taking it to the extreme, you can't create an instance of Person class without valid birth date and passport number. Now what? I did not downvote btw, there *are* valid reasons for bundling properties together in some class.

Comment: @artem that's the next step where interfaces comes into play. So a personweightheight interface could be something like that. You're getting caught up in the example I gave to make the point that what goes together should be together.

Answer (score 0):

To be frank, the culture is that Java programmers originally tended to come out of universities where Object Orientated principles and sustainable software design principles were taught.

As ErikE says in more words in his answer, you don't seem to be writing sustainable code. What I see from your example is there's a very awkward entanglement of concerns.

In Java culture you will tend to be aware of what libraries are available, and that will allow you to achieve much more than your off-the-cuff programming. So you would be trading out your idiosyncrasies for the design patterns and styles that had been tried and tested in hard core industrial settings.

But as you say, this isn't without downsides: today, having used Java for over 10 years, I tend to use either Node/Javascript or Go for new projects, because both allow quicker development, and with microservice-style architectures these are often suffice. Judging by the fact Google first was heavily using Java, but has been the originator of Go, I guess they might be doing the same. But even though I use Go and Javascript now, I still use many of the design skills I got from years of using and understanding Java.

Comment: Notably, the foobar recruitment tool that google uses allows for two languages to be used for solutions: java and python. I find it interesting that Go isn't an option.  I happened upon this [presentation on Go](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee380/Abstracts/100428-pike-stanford.pdf) and it has some interesting points about Java and Python (as well as other languages.)  For example there's one bullet point that stood out: "Perhaps as a result, non-expert programmers have confused "ease of use" with interpretation and dynamic typing."  Worth a read.

Comment: @JimmyJames just got to the slide saying 'in the hands of experts, they are great' -- good summary of the problem in the question